# Where did the name `atol` come from?

Tags: c

Anyone know what the source of the name of the function atol for converting a string to an long?

I thought about  Array To long but it's not sounds to me true.

Comment: It's Ascii TO Long, just as atoi is Ascii TO Int and atof is Ascii TO Float.

Comment: Actually, this is a misnomer, as `atoi()` must work on machines with a different primary character encoding (as long as the codes for numbers are in sequence). I've seen the alternative spelling as "*anything* to long", but that's not really good either ...

Answer (score 4):

ASCII To Long is what [`atol(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atol.3.html) means (in the early days of Unix, [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) was only used, and IIRC was mentioned in the [K&R book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language))

Today we usually use [UTF-8 everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/), but `atol` still works (since [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for digits uses the same encoding than ASCII)

On C implementations using another encoding (e.g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)) `atol` should still do what is expected (so `atol("345")` would give 345), since the C standard requires that the encoding of digit characters is consecutive. Its implementation might be more complex (or encoding specific).

<sup>so today, the `atol` name don't refer anymore to ASCII. The C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) don't mention ASCII (as mandatory) IIRC. you might rewrite history by reading `atol` as *anything to long* even if **historically** it was *ASCII to long*.</sup>

Comment: "C standard requires that the encoding of digit characters is consecutive." is true, yet `ato*()` also needs to cope with white-space, `+`, `-`, etc.whose encoding are not specified much.  IOWs this good answer stands fine w/o the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: I do believe that it is important to remind that C might not use ASCII (even if coding with EBCDIC is *very* unusual today). But the name of `atol` relates to the time where C was only on ASCII systems.

Answer (score 1):

It's Ascii to long, the same convention is used for `atoi` etc.

Comment: Thanks you, I think that when we know whats mean the name of functions is more easy to remember him.